# И опять помощь с пунтуацией

Tags: пунктуация

Как знаки препинания меняют смысл этого предложения? И не искажают ли его? Объясните: "Быстро смекнув, он решил попросить совет у старого друга - меня, больного и страдающего подростка".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Быстро смекнув, он решил попросить совет у старого друга - меня, больного и страдающего подростка.***

Пунктуационно предложение оформлено правильно.

*Запятая,* завершающая дееппричастный оборот, *запятая* перед распространённым приложением, относящимся к личному местоимению.

*Тире* в данном предложении уместно, требует выразительной паузы перед приложением *меня* и выделяет это слово.

Добавлю только, что слово *смекнув* обычно употребляется с последующим придачточным предложением: *смекнув, что с братцем так просто не справиться,*... (пример из нацкорпуса).

Так что стоит подумать над исправлением грамматического недочёта.

Answer (score 2):

С пунктуацией здесь всё нормально, но не хватает предлога перед местоимением "меня" (нужно "**у** меня"). Для наглядности сравните с такой парой реплик, где нехватка предлога очевидна:

> – У какого друга спросить?
>
> – Меня.

Примерно по такой же причине нужен предлог и в вашем предложении.

Answer (score 1):

Предложение с обособленным местоимением в качестве приложения некорректно, надо как-то исправить, например:

Быстро смекнув, он решил попросить совет у старого друга, то есть у меня, больного и страдающего подростка.

**Еще вариант:** Быстро смекнув, он решил попросить совет у старого друга, у меня, — больного и страдающего подростка.